# Highcharts running off local directory

Tags: http, highcharts

I am working with a js library named Highcharts and it is only working some of the time.

In all cases the links to the library are relative and I have proven that the code is not at faUlt (at least, not the code I have written). I am also loading a seperate library which works fine on all platforms.

If I load the page in IE the address is:

C:\path\to\file

If I upload it, then:

http://www.foo-bar.com/path/to/file

These both work.

However, if I open it locally in FF or Chrome, then the path is:

file:///C:/path/to/file

This last one doesn't work. Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you including the file in your source file? Just as a note, you will not be able to use the exact same include for a local file as in a file on the web.

Comment: All the referenced JS files in my source file are included relative to the file location.

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/Highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. My solution was to load the data as inline jSON, rather than link to a csv with the data in it.